# LUKS on software RAID not mounting on boot

Tags: encryption, raid, mdadm

I am trying to setup an encrypted disk using LUKS on a software RAID that was setup using `mdadm` on  14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.13.26 armv7l) (Odroid U3).

The problem is that the LUKS container is not automatically unlocked upon boot and I have no clue why or where to look for issues.

#### Problem

The software RAID is working fine if I format it with `ext4` and put it in the fstab for automounting.
Also if I use LUKS separately (without RAID, just on `/dev/sda1`) it works without problems and the device shows up in `/dev/mapper` when configured in `/etc/crypttab`.

The problem appears when combining the two. The RAID device shows up as `/dev/md0` but the LUKS container is not automatically mounted into `/dev/mapper/crypt`. On the other hand, using `sudo cryptdisks_start crypt` after booting works without any problems. Also, I ran `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` after setting up the `/etc/crypttab` (see output below).

#### mdadm

`sudo cat /proc/mdstat` gives the following output:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      976596800 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.6% (6345024/976596800) finish=1342.7min speed=12042K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

And the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` has the following line:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=f2c7b09f:71620ae5:7b6ec321:e9ce02cc name=odroid:0
```

#### crypttab

```
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
usb-crypt       /dev/md0                None            luks,keyscript=/home/user/key.sh
```

#### syslog

```
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.283025] md: bind<sda1>
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.302273] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.302817] md/raid1:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.302826] md/raid1:md0: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.302878] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 1000035123200
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.305140] md: resync of RAID array md0
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.305149] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.305153] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for resync.
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.305162] md: using 128k window, over a total of 976596800k.
Oct 22 06:34:40 odroid kernel: [    9.305166] md: resuming resync of md0 from checkpoint.
Oct 22 06:34:41 odroid kernel: [    9.499399]  md0: unknown partition table
```

#### update-initramfs

`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.13.26
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.13.23
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.8.13.23
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.8.13.23: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_PDBSh1/lib/modules/3.8.13.23/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_PDBSh1/lib/modules/3.8.13.23/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.13.18
grep: /boot/config-3.8.13.18: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.8.13.18
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.8.13.18: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_r2PYwd/lib/modules/3.8.13.18/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_r2PYwd/lib/modules/3.8.13.18/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

From what I understand this is kind of OK.

Comment: +1 Excellent question. I suspect this is an issue with the order in which mdadm volumes and cryptdisks are mounted during boot. Good starting points for investigation are (in `/etc`) `init.d/mdadm`, `init/cryptdisks`, and`init/cryptdisks-early`. Look at the start conditions to devise the running order or take a look at the boot logs.

Comment: Good point, thank you for the hint. The `/etc/init/cryptdisks` states `start on stopped udevtrigger or container` and I don't know how to put an init.d script as a dependency there (mdadm-raid is in `init.d`).I tried to override the upstart scripts for `cryptdisks` and `cryptdisks-udeve` and install the init.d scripts instead but this also didn't help. Is there a way to get more log-output somehow?